# How to make a "highlighter" effect for text background in CSS?

Tags: css, website-design

How would I go about highlighting an inline part of a paragraph decorated with a "highlighted" effect as if it were marked by a real highlighter on paper.

```
<p> The dog <em>jumped over</em> the lazy fox.</p>
```

Here I want to apply that effect to the em element. 
Im looking for something more than just `background-color: yellow`. Something thats a little non-linear.

For instance, something like in this picture -

[image: http://i.imgur.com/xXH1V6A.jpg]

Answer (score 3):

The proper way to do that is with the `<mark>` element. CSS alone can't produce that realistic effect. Therefore, you'd have to use some sort of graphic.

Comment: You are right. `mark` is the right element and yes, I guess one could use a graphic as a background and set proper spacing around the element.

Answer (score 3):

In case you choose to go for graphics, you could use CSS2 background images, and have a long fixed height graphic with the highlighter irregularities, or you could also use CSS3 border image effects, and use any height you want.

So for example, starting with a graphic like this:

[image]

You can use something like:

```
div#myElement { 
   border-image-source: url(../img/border-image.png); 
   border-image-slice:26; 
   border-width:26px; 
   border-image-outset:5px; 
   border-image-repeat: repeat;
   height:182px; 
   width:182px; 
}
```

And en up with this:

[image]

In both cases, you will need a graphic big enough to crate irregularities without looking like a pattern.

Source: [Crazy Egg Blog](http://blog.crazyegg.com/2012/05/11/css3-rounded-corners/)